# Redirecting to a page from the Select Menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use a select menu to redirect to another page in Rails.
I tried to add link_to to the select tag but it does not work.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use Javascript and the onClick event on the Select Element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function navigate(value) {
    switch (value) {
      case "1":
        document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        break;
      case "2":
        document.location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        break;
    }
  }
</script>

<select onchange="navigate(this.value)" >
  <option selected>Please Choose</option>
  <option value="1"> this page </option>
  <option value="2"> that page </option>
</select>
```